# Freeze both row and column in OpenOffice Calc

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-calc

How can I use freeze in OpenOffice Calc for both row and column so that the 1st row and 1st column will always be visible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
1) Select cell B2
2) Window -> Split
3) Window -> Freeze
```

Comment: yeah it worked, thx man! :)